# how to make command line in a multiline TextBox

Tags: c#, command-line, textbox

I am working with some electronics instruments using GPIB. I can communicate with instruments like this:

```
K2400.WriteString("*IDN?", true);
textBoxK2400.Text += K2400.ReadString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

The first line will execute a command, and in the second line I add the response of the last command to the textbox. How can I write the command in the textbox directly and add the response?

For example, if the user command entered after an indicator like ">>" and hitting ENTER, the response should be added in the next line of textbox.

So how can I read the last line of a textbox and add the respone in a new line? I am looking for a method like:

```
private void Execute(string command)
{
  K2400.WriteString(command, true);
  textBoxK2400.Text += K2400.ReadString() + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Comment: Surely it would be easier to use a normal textbox for input, and a second for output?

Comment: Yeah it would be easier but it is not professional :P

Comment: ...not professional? I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: because a lot of commands should entered by user, typing in a textbox and clicking on a execute button would be troublesome in long run. So I am lookig for the fastest way that is just type in the multiline text box and hit enter, get result.

Comment: You can set a button on a form to be the form's default, which means hitting enter would cause the event attached to the button to be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
private void textBoxK2400_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        string command = textBoxK2400.Text.Split('\n').LastOrDefault();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(command) && command.StartsWith(">>"))
        {
            K2400.WriteString(command.Substring(2), true);
            textBoxK2400.Text += K2400.ReadString() + Environment.NewLine;
            textBoxK2400.Text += ">>"; // It's not necessary
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, this is a good starting point. But how to take care of event when user hits enter?

Comment: This will flicker when the text is getting longer.

Comment: Why the downvote? Talk about this: if there is something wrong I'd like to correct. Let me understand, please.

Comment: @Fischermaen: there are a lot of _troubles_ with this approach, flickering is only the last. I've just tried to answer OP question. For example I upvoted StefanE's answer, because I think that's the right way to show a UI. But I just tried to answer OP question, no more ;)

Answer (score 5):

Use two Text boxes(textbox and a listbox might be better) but make them look as "one" textbox.. If using WPF it could look pretty nice and in Windows form possible at least.

Did a quick test..

[image]

And with this code for KeyPress event for the textbox:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
            textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
            listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a brilliant idea, I probably end up going with this way but because of my orginal question I have to give the answer to Marco's answer.

Answer (score 1):

> private void Execute(string command) { K2400.WriteString(command,
>   true); textBoxK2400.Text += K2400.ReadString() + Environment.NewLine;
>   }

this is it. I'd just recommend to 'buffer' a part of the text, not all, because it could be long by the end. You can split it to lines before and take a number of lines (i. e. 10).

And **don't forget** to make the field black and the text green, it looks much more professional when the command field is decorated such way.

Comment: @Sean87: well, you could use also a RichTextBox and use different colors for user input and machine response...

Answer (score 0):

Well first i would suggest a RichTextBox to use.
To capture ENTER you should use KeyPress Event .

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            { 
                string LastLine = richTextBox1.Lines[richTextBox1.Lines.Length-2];
                if (LastLine.StartsWith(">>"))
                {
                    //here you can filter the LastLine
                    K2400.WriteString(LastLine, true);
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(K2400.ReadString() + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    //here you can unwrite the last line
                    string[] totalLines = richTextBox1.Lines;
                    richTextBox1.Text = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalLines.Length - 2; i++)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(totalLines[i]+Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("That was not a valid command");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is a problem, when I hit enter the command will be executed but the character blinker will jump to the first row of the richtextbox.

Comment: -1 A RichTextBox for entering a command makes no sense. RichTextBox uses a lot of resources, because it can do formating.

Comment: @Fischermaen then using the same Code snippet he can move to a TextBox and i don't know if it matter's to -1 this after i wroted code which does the Job no matter if RichTextBox or TextBox i think you did that to show you're Ego not because of the RichTextBox usage !